# Отсортировать один список по другому с доп. условиями

Tags: python, list, filter

Есть 2 списка (одн-ый, мног-ый). Нужно отсортировать второй список по первому (объеденить эти элементы списка в один). Чтобы элементы первого, соответствовали значениям второго и наоборот второй=первому.
Но есть одно если во втором списке есть элемент, который содержит в конце символ подчеркивания (_), то нужно считать его правильным и он должен входить в список.

```
lst1 = ['DAY', 'MONTH', 'CLASS', 'ID']
lst2 = [['DAY', '01'], ['MONTH', '07'], ['DELETED', 'N'], ['ID_', '33']]
```

Должно получиться как то так

```
lst_end = [['DAY', '01'], ['MONTH', '07'], ['ID_', '33']]
```

Я нашел такой вариант

```
lst_end = sorted(filter(lambda x: x[0] in lst1, lst2),
                     key=lambda x: lst1.index(x[0]))
```

Но он исключает элемент `ID_` Есть ли какой то просто вариант не исключать такие элементы при фильтрации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно по частичному совпадению, тогда:

```
lst1 = ['DAY', 'MONTH', 'CLASS', 'ID']
lst2 = [['DAY', '01'], ['MONTH', '07'], ['DELETED', 'N'], ['ID_', '33']]

lst_end = [
    [name, value] for name, value in lst2 
    if any(name.startswith(x) for x in lst1)
]
print(lst_end)
```

Результат:

```
[['DAY', '01'], ['MONTH', '07'], ['ID_', '33']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант для разнообразия - делаем из списка 1 множество, чтобы быстрее проверки на вхождение работали, и добавляем в него такие же элементы, но с подчёркиванием:

```
set1 = set(lst1) | set(f'{x}_' for x in lst1)
lst_new = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in set1, lst2))
print(lst_new)
# [['DAY', '01'], ['MONTH', '07'], ['ID_', '33']]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А обратный вариант как получить,т.е чтобы элементы lst1 были в списке lst2? `lst_end = [['DAY', '01'], ['MONTH', '07'], ['ID', '33']]`